# No "/data/logs""directory. Is it hidden? Not on my version?

Tags: internal-storage

I am having the "INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE" error when trying to do some app development. Googling around and looking here I see a lot of advice saying to empty the "/data/logs" folder.

Only I cant find that anywhere.
I have looked with the normal file manager (with rout permissions), as well as trying a few tools like SD Maid and Disk Usage. But no sign of it. Ditto with terminal and manually looking. The data folder just does not container a "logs" folder. And nor does data\data for that mater.

I am using CyanogenMod M10.0.0 Beta 1 on a HTC Legend. Android version 4.1.2

Is this folder not on my version? is it somewhere else?

The behavior seems to match. I was just constantly using usb debugging and sending my own app over from eclipse to test, my own app being tiny (well under 1MB). Then I started getting "INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE". So I assume *something* is building up/wasting space from the dozens of compiles and crashes I have had today.

Thanks for any help,

Thomas